# How to add link to text in html (so when you click you go to a website)

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I have the bellow code:

```
<div id="twoBtn" class="mainContainer"><!--two buttons-->
<p>Find us on the app store, or send us an email bellow!</p>
<!--<a href="#" id="btn1" class="button1">
    <img src="Resources/images/apple.png">
    <span>App Store</span>
  </a>-->
<a href="#" id="btn2" class="button2">
    <!--<img src="Resources/images/android.png">-->
    <span>Contact us</span>
  </a>
```

**I would like the *app store* to be a link the user can click on. How can I do this?**

Comment: How do I add a link with that? As in web link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your question would be

```
<div id="twoBtn" class="mainContainer"><!--two buttons-->
<p>
  Find us on the 
    <a href="#your_link" >
      app store
    </a>
  , or send us an email bellow!
</p>
<a href="#" id="btn2" class="button2">
<!--<img src="Resources/images/android.png">-->
    <span>Contact us</span>
</a>
```

It will make your "app store" a link and you can ssign classes and IDs to this `a` tag.